# Регулярные выражения EXT js

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid-layout

Создал Динамический грид панел 
Код добавления колонок и фиелдсов

```
store_.on('load', function () {
    store_.data.each(function(item, index, totalItems ) {
        columns_.push({header: item.data.nameRu,flex: 3,dataIndex: item.data.eName,sortable: true});
        fields_.push({name: item.data.eName,type: 'string'});    
    });
});
```

в БД у меня есть поле `eName` - где хранятся мои `Entity`. Проблема в том что я не могу поставить регулярные выражение на дату пробовал в самом `Entity` таким вот образом `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` 
но в результате `1989-06-22 18:00:00.0 UTC` выходит так. А мне нужно задать выражения `dd.mm.yyyy. Когда в`entity`вместо`DATE`ставлю`String`выходит тоже самое только без`UTC`.

Comment: в геттер или в сеттер не пробовал так писать ?       DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
    String strDate = df.format(myDate);

Comment: пробовал не помогло

Comment: Точнее сформулируете какой формат даты у вас при получении от бекэнда, и какой формат вам нужен выходе. Укажите версию extjs.

Comment: 4.2.4 версия нужен dd.mm.yyyy